# Adding nuget files to Different folders in a Visual Studio project

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I have a private hosted nuget repository with a .nupkg including several DLL files. These files are compiled C++ plugins for interacting with hardware, printers, cameras etc. I also have a c# project, which is set as the startup project in my solution. The usual way I'm adding these DLLs is to press "Add Existing Item" on my project and set the `Build Action` to `Content` and `Copy to output Directory` to `Copy if Newer`. So when built, the DLLs can be found in the output directory.

I want to simply this process by having these files in a nuget repo, but when pressing the "Manage Nuget Packages" on the project, these files are only added as Reference. How can I define where nuget is adding my DLL files? Is it event possible?

Comment: When you build the project, aren't the DLLs automatically copied to the output directory, because they are referenced?

Comment: @BorisEetgerink Changed the question a bit. Please have a look.

Comment: Why do you need to specify where the DLLs are placed? If that's clear, there might be another way to accomplish that.

Comment: @BorisEetgerink It has to do with the framework created around the application. Using reflection to load certain assemblies located in different folder etc.